# How to pass the information on adapter inside a listener.

Tags: java, android, adapter, onclicklistener

The `int` "pos" is not passing correctly.
How I can the to correct value when the `ImageView` is `OnClick()`.
It seems when the `listener` activate the information is not accurate anymore.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder vHolder;
    if (convertView != null)
        vHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    else {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.car_list, null);
        vHolder = new ViewHolder();
        vHolder.textView = ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCarListText));
        vHolder.textView2 = ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCarDescriptionListText));
        vHolder.imageView = ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivCarListMenuIcon));
        vHolder.relativeLayout = ((RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout));
        convertView.setTag(vHolder);


        CarItem c = mItems.get(position);
        final int pos = (int)c.getCarID();

        vHolder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showCarEditDialog(pos); //THIS IS PASSING WRONG <--------------
            }
        });
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ImageView.setTag()` to get position of clicked row on ImageVIew click as:

```
vHolder.imageView.setTag(pos);  // set current pos
vHolder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        showCarEditDialog(Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString()));
    }
});
```

Comment: @rnascimento13: I appreciate the answer by prosper K.just for sake of simplicity, I have added another way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily do it like this :

```
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder vHolder;
    if (convertView != null)
        vHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    else {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.car_list, null);
        vHolder = new ViewHolder();
        vHolder.textView = ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCarListText));
        vHolder.textView2 = ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvCarDescriptionListText));
        vHolder.imageView = ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivCarListMenuIcon));
        vHolder.relativeLayout = ((RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout));
        convertView.setTag(vHolder);


    }

        vHolder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                showCarEditDialog((int)((CarItem)mItems.get(position)).getCarId);
            }
        });

    return convertView;
}
```